# Sqlserver GROUP BY sin tener en cuenta la fecha

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql-server-2017

Estoy tratando de seleccionar los items de una tabla de sqlserver y agruparlos por el número de documento de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT  codigo_inventario,
        CAST(Fecha_Inventario as DATE) as Fecha_inventario,
        Ubicacion,
        COUNT(codigo_inventario) as cantidad_registros 
FROM [dbo].[WMS_Inventario] 
GROUP BY codigo_inventario,CAST(Fecha_Inventario as DATE) , Ubicacion
```

Pero necesito agrupar los elementos así estén creados en diferentes fechas. La respuesta de la consulta es la siguiente.

```
1   2021-02-09  00101   3
1   2021-02-09  BODPR   1
2   2021-02-09  BODPR   1
3   2021-02-09  BODPR   3
3   2021-02-11  BODPR   2
```

El documento número 3 no se está agrupando porque la fecha es diferente, estoy tratando de que solo tome la primera fecha para poder agrupar los datos.

Comment: Pero si solo tomas una fecha del documento 3 ¿no estarás perdiendo para el agrupamiento los valores de esa fecha que planeas no elegir?

Comment: Necesito mostrar solo la fecha de inicio, que es la que tiene  el primer registro insertado

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Usando **MIN()** para traer el primer registro de la fecha

```
SELECT  codigo_inventario,
        CAST(MIN(Fecha_Inventario) as DATE) as Fecha_inventario,
        Ubicacion,
        COUNT(codigo_inventario) as cantidad_registros 
FROM [dbo].[WMS_Inventario] 
GROUP BY codigo_inventario , Ubicacion
```

Si funciona

Con el Tuyo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el mio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Regresa la misma respuesta de la consulta y aún no agrupa por fecha

Comment: No lo copiaste verdad? y solo pusiste el min, se me olvido comentarte que quites la fecha del group by

Answer (score 0):

Esta fue la solución, no es necesario poder el campo de la fecha dentro del GROUP BY

```
SELECT  codigo_inventario,
 MIN(CAST(Fecha_Inventario as DATE)) as Fecha_inventario,
        Ubicacion,
        COUNT(codigo_inventario) as cantidad_registros 
FROM [dbo].[WMS_Inventario] 
GROUP BY codigo_inventario, Ubicacion
```